# std::map design: why map accept comparator as template parameter

Tags: c++, stl, boost, dictionary

Map type from STL have next type:

```
std::map< Key, Data, Compare, Alloc >
```

As one of template parameters we could pass `Compare` predicate, why map accept this predicate as template parameter and not as object in constructor?

It could has more flexible interface with something like `boost::function< bool, const T&, const T& >` in constructor.
Ofcourse I'm understend that when STL was designed boost does not exists, but designers could be create something similar on boost::function.

I belive it has some deep reasons.

**EDITED**
Sorry for dummy question, map have same posibility :)
My question doesn't have sense after your answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Map DOES have such a constructor. From section 23.3.1 of the C++ Standard:

```
explicit map(const Compare& comp = Compare(),
const Allocator& = Allocator());
```

Comment: +1 - Thank you. 
But sorry, I've accepted Rob's answer because he was early than you.

Comment: Actually, Neil's answer was earlier by about 3 minutes, so if you're using submission time as a tie-breaker for otherwise equally helpful answers, then please award the acceptance to this answer.

Answer (score 7):

The template argument is the *type* of the predicate, not the value. The value *can* be provided as an argument to the constructor. You can specify any value that matches the type. As given, the default type is `std::less<Key>`, which pretty much only has one value, but you should be able to specify your own type for the `Compare` argument, including `boost::function`, and then use various values to control the behavior of your map objects.

Comment: Ok. I am newbie on this site and don't know rules about awarding. But I suspect it depended from speed. Anyway, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Because `boost::function` is polymorphic, it cannot be inlined. The design of the STL is aimed at maximum potential for the compiler to do inlining of code, which is easy on expanded templates; also you could easily make the decision to use `boost::function` to supply the comparison with `std::map` if you needed it to be polymorphic.

Comment: nice point, but std solution is more nice)) thank you for help.

Comment: I think the second part of your question about "deep reasons" is perfectly valid, not dumb! :) By the way, std::tr1::function is already semi-standard, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_Report_1

Answer (score 2):

Using a compare object creates a run-time cost - the object needs to be stored, and the comparison must occur through a pointer. By using a class, the comparison can simplify down into a single expression, for example when using int keys. The goal of the standard library was to be no less efficient than what a good C++ programmer would generate on their own.

Comment: 'The goal of the standard library was to be no less efficient than what a good C++ programmer would generate on their own' -- Nice point too. +1 for remember me that.